# Getting a JavaScript error on a virtually empty page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[This is my website.](http://dev.goblinhammer.com/)

I'm getting the following error in the JavaScript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined background.js:65

I have no clue why this would be. I don't even have a `background.js` file. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? (The answer is yes — try clicking `background.js` and seeing if it has a helpful comment.)

Comment: What browser? Not getting it in Chrome.  Suspect an extension issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue!

Comment: I won't delete this question for others that may have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an extension; their errors for a given page also show up in the Chrome console. You should be able to click the filename; it’ll open up in the Resources panel and tell you which one.

Answer (score 1):

background.js will belong to one of your Chrome extensions. It is used as a background process for the extension.

You should disable your extensions one by one until you find the one that is causing the error. And of course submit a bug report to the extension creator.